# How to get value from combo box and print on an image with php

Tags: php, html

I want to get the value from a combo box which I have created using html

My html code is:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" name="name">
<select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control input-lg" maxlength="12">
<input type="button" name="next1">
    <option value="male">male</option>
    <option value="female">female</option>
</select>
```

and to print my combo box text in an image my php code is

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('Desert.jpg');
$white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 73, 41, 236);
$font_path = 'OpenSans-Italic.TTF';
$text= $_GET['name']; 
$text2= $_GET['gender'];
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $text);
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $text2);
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
imagedestroy($jpg_image);
```

As you can see, in my php code I have tried to get the value with the `$_GET['gender'];` also but that is of no use it only shows a plain image without a text on it.  What am I doing wrong? and i have used java script for subbmitting the values.

Comment: What method you use for your form? GET/POST?

Comment: @IvanDokov actually I have used none of them without that also we get get a value from html to php but i have donw that with input tag getting value from html to php without using any on the form

Comment: Assigning text to `$text2` variable and using `$text` variable for a picture? Really?

Comment: @u_mulder Its was just my typing mistake I have checked my codes they have `$text2` only so now also not working .

Comment: Have you checked `$text2` value? What it contains?

Comment: it contains `$_GET['gender']` gender is the name given by me to combo box

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your variables mixed up.

```
$text2= $_GET['gender'];
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $text);
```

You are using `$text` in the `imagettftext` but you assigned `$_GET['gender']` to `$text2`.  You might try:

```
$gender= $_GET['gender'];
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $gender);
```

Keeping the `$_GET` and variable names the same should help you from getting confused.

If you are using a form to post this then you should most likely be using:

```
$gender= $_POST['gender'];
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $gender);
```

but, without your `<form>` code we don't know how this information is getting submitted.

(You can also drop the `maxlength` property from your select object)

Comment: If you update your question to include more of your code you might get better help - it's hard to guess what all you are doing.

Comment: I have tried with input tag also without using form its working but not with combo box

Comment: i have edited it if this is enough info. then please give me the solution or may also give the java script

Comment: Sorry, here to help, not to do your work for you.  You still need to post more of your code if you want help and if the above is all of your code you've got a long way to go.